# Lexicon Alpha not detected by Ubuntu

Tags: sound, usb

I just got a Lexicon Alpha usb audio interface, but it's not showing up as a usb device or as a sound card.

Comment: Please add a tiny bit more detail to your question: what Ubuntu release are you using, how do you know it is not being detected by the system? Can you give us some logs?

Comment: My Lexicon shows up as just "Digitech" under `lsusb` and has more correct info in the listing from `usb-devices`. However, it does not appear to show up when running `sudo lshw` in the terminal. It also shows up in System Settings->Sound, and in `pavucontrol`, as well as being usable by JACK.

Comment: [solved] I removed pluseaudio and used the alsa hw:2,0 ; works great now. Sorry for leaving the question open.

Comment: BTW - for musicians, (from what I've read and tried) it's best if pulseaudio is removed.

Answer (score 0):

Try unplugging the USB cable and plugging it back in. This might trigger detection.

I have Lexicon Alpha with Kubuntu system (and Win7 dual boot). Linux and Windows does not detect the stupid sound card on login, I must manually unplug the USB cable and plug it again to detect the card, everytime!

Comment: for some reason it battles with the primary sound card for hw:0,0 when you boot. Unplugging at every shutdown/restart and plugging in after reboot (after everything loads) is a must.